# Grab the last octet in an IP address using Python

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that will take an IP address in CIDR format (ie. 1.1.1.0/32 or 10.0.0.1/24) and split the IP into three parts: the first three octets (1.1.1), the last octet (0) and the Subnet mask (32). The IP will be of variable length so I don't know if I can use some sort of string character counter.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Python 3.3 has a [`ipaddress` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) that can handle CIDR-formatted masks just fine. There is a [port](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipaddress) available for Python 2.6 / 2.7.

Comment: If you are using subnet masks, why do you care about octect boundaries? Don't you actually want: network number, host number, and subnet mask?

Comment: This question is old.  But for new-comers I strongly second Martjin Pieters recommendation to use the ipaddress module as it handles subnets and ipv6 (which is starting to turn up regularly).

All of the regex solutions below are out of date I'd argue.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions can be cumbersome. You can also use the split() function

```
inp = '192.168.0.1/24'
ip, submask = inp.split('/')
octets = ip.split('.')
```

Answer (score 3):

Parse the IP into an int, and use bitwise operators to get it.

Another way would be to use a library like [ipaddr-py](http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/). I'd personally prefer the library.

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re


def extractIP( ipStr):

    l = re.split('(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)/(.*)', ipStr)
    return l[1:-1]

print extractIP("1.2.3.45/35")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ipstring="192.168.1.1/12"
s=re.split(r"\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\/(\d+)\b",ipstring)
print s
['', '192.168.1', '1', '12', '']
print s[1]
192.168.1
print s[2]
1
print s[3]
12
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions. You can split all the octets into a list using r'.' and then recombine them in whatever order you like. You could write a more complicated re to do it in one stroke, but i think that'd be a bit harder.

```
import re
ip = '1.1.1.1/32'
re.split(r'(\.|/)', ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression would be simple in this situation.

```
(\d{,3}\.\d{,3}\.\d{,3})\.(\d{,3})\/(\d+)
```

Using the `re.match` method in conjunction would yield your result.